# JavaFX update text from Task

Tags: java, javafx

I want to change text I create a task and increment `i`, but I want to set a new text on this same place when `i` is changed, but old text doesn't disappear. It's my code. On swing I will be use `repaint()`

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
          final int finalI = i;
          Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String a = "aaa";
                if(finalI>4){
                    a = "sadsa";
                }
                if(finalI>10){
                    a = "sadsadsadsadsad";
                }
                gc.fillText(a, 150, 250+10);
            }
          });
          i++;
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
};
Thread th = new Thread(task);
th.setDaemon(true);
th.start();
```

Comment: Are you using a `Canvas` and drawing to its `GraphicContext`? Because in this case the last text is still there, because `Canvas` is really like a drawing board. If you want to store references I would propose to use a `Pane` and put `Shape` objects on it.

Comment: JavaFX is event-driven and single-threaded. This means that repaint and event response can not be done simultaneously. Long-running task should be executed on separate thread so they do not block the rendering of the UI, When the task is finished it can sync back to the FX thread by calling FX.deferAction() which will simply execute the code on the main thread. LOOK AT THIS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528313/force-immediate-paint-in-javafx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the problem is that `Canvas` really acts like a drawing board. You have drawn some text on it then you have drawn another text without erasing the previous text.

In your case, when you want to store a reference to the text to be able to update it, it is more reasonable to use a [`Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) and put a [`Text`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) instance on it.

**I have created an example for you**:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

            Pane pane = new Pane();
            Text text = new Text("");
            pane.getChildren().add(text);
            Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
                String a = "Initial text";

                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    int i = 0;

                    while (true) {

                        if (i > 4)
                            a = "I is bigger than 4";

                        if (i > 10)
                            a = "I is bigger than 10";

                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            text.setText(a);
                            // If you want to you can also move the text here
                            text.relocate(10, 10);
                        });

                        i++;
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread th = new Thread(task);
            th.setDaemon(true);
            th.start();

            root.setCenter(pane);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Note:** You can also eliminate the `Platform.runlater(...)` block by updating the [`messageProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#messageProperty%28%29) of the task inside `call()` then binding the `textProperty` of the `Text` to this property.

**Example:**

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
Text text = new Text("");
text.relocate(10, 10);

pane.getChildren().add(text);
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    {
        updateMessage("Initial text");
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        int i = 0;

        while (true) {
            if (i > 4)
                updateMessage("I is bigger than 4");

            if (i > 10)
                updateMessage("I is bigger than 10");

            i++;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
};

text.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());

Thread th = new Thread(task);
th.setDaemon(true);
th.start();
```

Comment: Ooo thank you for help !! I want to click that the answer is helpful . Thank you for help

Comment: I have one more question can I have in one Pane maybe three diffrent Text text = new Text("") with diffrent location ?

Comment: Of course, as many as you want. You can add them like `Text text = new Text("sample"); pane.getChildren().add(text);`. Then you can set the location with `text.relocate(100,100);`.

Comment: ok thanks for explain. And one more question . If I want drawImage maybe one time near one text when i >10 the image will be near diffrent text. But first image is disapear. Can I do this ?

Comment: Yes of course. You can also add `ImageView` instances to the `Pane`. If you stored the reference as before: `Platform.runLater(() -> pane.getChildren().remove(imageView));` will remove the image from the `Pane`.

Comment: I think I do something wrong I do this : ImageView v = new ImageView(busStop); a bustop is a image. next I do this :  if (i > 4){
                 updateMessage("I is bigger than 4"); 
                 ImageView v = new ImageView(busStop);
                 v.relocate(10, 250);
              pane.getChildren().add(v);
                 }

Comment: But I don't see a image on screen

Comment: `v.relocate(10, 250); pane.getChildren().add(v);` should be `Platform.runLater(() -> { pane.getChildren().add(v); v.relocate(10, 250);});`. Updating the GUI should always should happen on the FX application thread, and that's what `Platform.runLater` does.

Comment: Ok thank you now I know what and how I can do this, I have one more question when I finish this I will have a diffrent question , how I can do in java fx somethink like Cardlayout in swing. I have 3 stage and I want show one time one stage sometime second stage

Comment: As you said it is a different question, so please ask this in another question:)