# How to wait for Canvas/GraphicsContext to complete task before continuing block of code?

Tags: java, javafx

How would I force the GraphicsContext or Canvas to wait for the drawing tasks to be completed before continuing down the block?

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

gc.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
gc.drawImage(pause, firstImageX, y);
gc.drawImage(cancel, leftImageX, y);
gc.drawImage(complete, rightImageX, y);

Platform.runLater(() -> {
     try {
         gc.wait();
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
});

//other stuff
```

I have tried

```
try {
     gc.wait();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and it does update the canvas but I get an error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at captureGIF.CaptureGIF.lambda$null$6(CaptureGIF.java:176)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "wait for the drawing tasks to be completed before continuing down the block"? All this code is in a single thread; the statements are all executed in order. So the `//other stuff` is not executed until the previous lines of code are completed, whatever you do. (The method `wait()` is a low-level synchronization method used to manage multithreading at a very base level. It is almost certainly not doing what you think it is doing - whatever that is.)

Comment: Doing a bit more research allowed me to realize that canvas repainting is done on the same thread as seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528313/force-immediate-paint-in-javafx so I made my other code start in another thread allowing for it to repaint. Thanks!